# Firebase cloud function delays when calling "itself", through another service

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I have a use case where 2 cloud functions are used subsequently. However, these functions are not called that often and therefore, cold-boots are occurring quite regularly. In order to circumvent the double cold-boot times, I figured I could combine the functionality of each individual cloud function in a single cloud function and determine based on the request type what functionality to perform (see example code).

```
exports.foo = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  if(req.body.webAppRequest){
    res.json(await dialogflow.detectIntent(req.body.request));
  } else {
    res.json(await fulfillment());
  }
}
```

The call order is as follows:
Webapp <-> (Cloud function) NLPProxy <-> Dialogflow <-> (Cloud function) Fulfillment

The NLPProxy calls Dialogflow, Dialogflow then calls the Fulfillment, the Fulfillment returns a value to Dialogflow and Dialogflow to the NLPProxy. The NLPProxy awaits this result and finally returns the request to the web app. However, there is a big delay (5+ seconds) when this functionality is in the same cloud function. When either the fulfillment or proxy is moved to a separate function there is no more delay.

What can be the cause of this added delay? Is there some sort of protection to prevent a function from calling itself? Although the function is calling 'itself' through Dialogflow, so this shouldn't be seen as the same call.

I know that executions in the simulator are performed subsequently, but this problem also occurs when the functions have been deployed..

I have been breaking my head over this the past hours, hopefully someone here as any clue on what could be the cause of this.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you are using `await` without `async`.  That doesn't look valid.

Comment: @DougStevenson My apologies, this was just a piece of example code I quickly wrote in StackOverflow. The code itself is working and properly returning. The only problem is the delay when this function is called for both the NLPProxy and the fulfillment code. If one of hem is handled by another function, their is no significant delay (of 5+ seconds)